# Order of draggable entries and assets won't save

Tags: assets, control-panel, entry-type, sorting

Hello Craft Community,

I have a site which has just over 300 entries but most entries have several asset fields, entry fields, or complex matrices.

My problem is that when on an existing entry, I cannot drag-to-reorder any items in an asset or entry field-type. The CP will let me reorder, but saving the entry does not retain my new ordering.

There are no console errors related to this problem, so I'm looking for advise on where to start troubleshooting.

Thanks!

*Edit: additional note that my PHP runtime config variables seem to be in order, 256M memory, 3000 max_input_vars, etc.*

Comment: Hey Michael, this sounds like some sort of bug. I'd recommend submitting a help ticket directly from your dashboard. Be sure to include your logs, database, and file backup.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, if I had to guess, you're running into a php.ini [max_input_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars), [post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) or some other related environmental limitation.  I'd try bumping those as a starting point for debugging.

Comment: Hi Brad, the max_input_vars is 3000, post_max_size is 256M. There's not a log event being created that I can see. Any other place to look? Thanks.

Comment: I also want to add that the POST by the edit page is passing the correct order:
`fields[pageContent][2126][fields][image][]:1792
fields[pageContent][2126][fields][image][]:1791`

But in the database they do not have this ordering.

Comment: Anything getting logged in `craft/storage/runtime/logs/phperrors.log`? Or search for `[error]` in `craft/storage/runtime/logs/craft.log` files.

Comment: Hi Brad, unfortunately nothing is being written to those files when I try to make a reorder save.